Prevent Figures and Tables from floating in R Markdown
Is it possible to prevent Figures and Tables from floating in R Markdown with .pdf output?
Every try a LaTex solution, I geet the following error:
A new version of TeX Live has been released. If you need to install or update any LaTeX packages, you have to upgrade TinyTeX with tinytex::reinstall_tinytex(). If it fails to upgrade, you might be using a default random CTAN mirror that has not been fully synced to the main CTAN repository, and you need to wait for a few more days or use a CTAN mirror that is known to be up-to-date (see the "repository" argument on the help page ?tinytex::install_tinytex).

tlmgr: Local TeX Live (2021) is older than remote repository (2024).
Cross release updates are only supported with
  update-tlmgr-latest(.sh/.exe) --update
See https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html for details.
! LaTeX Error: File `multirow.sty' not found.

! Emergency stop.


Does this answer your question? Otherwise, an example with your specific issue would be helpful.

Not quite. I can't seem to use any LaTex solution. I edited my question.

Ah I see. Have you tried running tinytex::reinstall_tinytex()

That actually made the error disapper, but tables are still floating! This is the solution I'm trying: kableExtra::kable_styling(latex_options = "hold_position")

Please have a look again at this url and see if you can configure the heading / preamble or the figure environment itself to suit your needs. If any of its proposed solutions don't work for you, add a sample rmarkdown document describing what's being rendered and where you want the figures to actually go.

I worked it out. See my suggested answer. Thank you for your time.

I actually found a solution with kableExtra::kable_styling(latex_options = "hold_position"). Please note that, if you're encountering some form of tinytex error, tinytex::reinstall_tinytex() might do the work -suggested by @Felix Jassler-.

Good to see you found a solution :)
